# How to configure jira external issue tracker on gitlab

Tags: jira, gitlab

I can't find any information about how to configure jira as external issue tracker on gitlab.

I've tried writing the following on /etc/gitlab/gitlab-rc but is seems that it does nothing. I execute the "gitlab-ctl reconfigure" but then gitlab.yml have no changes, and I don't see any Jira option on project settings.

etc/gitlab/gitlab.rb:

```
gitlab-rails['issues_tracker'] = "jira"
gitlab-rails['issues_tracker_jira_title'] = " Atlassian Jira"
gitlab-rails['issues_tracker_jira_project_url'] = "http://myjiraserver/issues/?jql=project=:issues_tracker_id"
gitlab-rails['issues_tracker_jira_issues_url'] = "http://myjiraserver/browse/:id"
gitlab-rails['issues_tracker_jira_new_issue_url'] = "http://myjiraserver/secure/CreateIssue.jspa"
```

Comment: Have your tried what is explained in docs? http://doc.gitlab.com/ee/integration/jira.html

Comment: What kind of GitLab install did you choose ? [Omnibus](https://about.gitlab.com/downloads/) or the [manual install](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/blob/master/doc/install/installation.md) ? I don't know all the version of GitLab, but isn't the correct file name for these properties `/etc/gitlab/gitlab.rb` ?

Comment: I wrote wrong file name on the question, it is gitlab.rb

Comment: In the docs, tells that you have to uncomment de jira lines directory into the gitlab.yml, but I haven't such lines, and when you run gitlab-ctl reconfigure this file is rewritten.

Comment: I've installed gitlab with omnibus.

Answer (score 2):

If you use the following:

```
gitlab_rails['issues_tracker_jira'] = true
gitlab_rails['issues_tracker_jira_title'] = " Atlassian Jira"
gitlab_rails['issues_tracker_jira_project_url'] = "http://myjiraserver/jira/issues/?jql=project=:issues_tracker_id"
gitlab_rails['issues_tracker_jira_issues_url'] = "http://myjiraserver/jira/browse/:id"
gitlab_rails['issues_tracker_jira_new_issue_url'] = "http://myjiraserver/jira/secure/CreateIssue.jspa"
```

It should work; your first rule isn't formatted as gitlab expects it to be :) (add the rules and then 'gitlab-ctl reconfigure')

Comment: It's been a while since I've worked with JIRA, what's not working for you exactly?

Comment: I tried to integrate the JIRA Gitlab by Admin area -> Service template-> JIRA.
After my changes, I accept the merge request in Gitlab but that incident are not listed in JIRA.

Comment: Try checking out project-specific settings for services, since the service templates actually don't apply to existing projects :)